# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor vs Java Executorservice cachedthreadpool

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

What are the pros and cons of using

Spring  [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) vs  Java [Executorservice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) `cachedthreadpool` even though spring is wrapper of Java concurrency.

Just would like to know the flexibility in using them.

Comment: They're the same thing: ThreadPoolExecutor is an instance of ExecutorService. You should read the javadoc.

Comment: If you are developing App using `Spring` then make sense to use [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) otherwise use [Executorservice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) as it will be independent of `Spring` and can be used anywhere else.

Comment: title of question should be Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor vs Java Executorservice cachedthreadpool .. and not Pros & cons of Thread pool. because this question doesnt cover that

Comment: IMHO the main advantage of using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is that you can use it along `@Async` annotation https://dzone.com/articles/spring-and-threads-async

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the added Advantage of using  **ThreadPoolTaskExecutor** of spring  is that it is well suited for  management and monitoring (e.g. **through JMX**), providing several useful attributes: **"corePoolSize", "maxPoolSize", "keepAliveSeconds" (all supporting updates at runtime); "poolSize", "activeCount".**

apart from that it is obviously simple to use if you already have spring injections implemented in your application. by using it you can  directly inject thread pool by setter injection like below:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
</bean>
```

[ThreadPoolTaskExecutor Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html)

on the other hand **ExecutorService CachedThreadPool** is good utility to share your most recent under utilized threads ( **Under 60 seconds** ).  It is important to point out that CachedThreadPool is not separate class 
its method ( newCachedThreadPool() ) .

[CachedThreadPool Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29)

Comment: i have seen everywhere the value of corePoolSize" value="5" "maxPoolSize" value="10" not other no. , what is the logic behind it ?

Comment: Why can't I do the same with, for example, the raw java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor? It also exposes properties as public setter/getter methods. I don't understand why Spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor helps in JMX (I haven't worked with it) or XML property configurations when it has "public void setMaxPoolSize(int maxPoolSize)" while the raw java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor also has "public void setMaximumPoolSize(int maximumPoolSize)". I mean, what value does it add.

Comment: And as for "supporting updates at runtime" - doesn't the raw java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor support it as well? According to the javadocs of, for example, setMaximumPoolSize() it takes care of such a scenario.

Comment: From the spring docs: JavaBean that allows for configuring a ThreadPoolExecutor in bean style (through its "corePoolSize", "maxPoolSize", "keepAliveSeconds", "queueCapacity" properties) and exposing it as a Spring TaskExecutor. This class is also well suited for management and monitoring (e.g. through JMX), providing several useful attributes: "corePoolSize", "maxPoolSize", "keepAliveSeconds" (all supporting updates at runtime); "poolSize", "activeCount" (for introspection only).

Answer (score 1):

After Googling you will get the following:

**Executorservice**

The java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService interface represents an asynchronous execution mechanism which is capable of executing tasks in the background. An ExecutorService is thus very similar to a thread pool. In fact, the implementation of ExecutorService present in the java.util.concurrent package is a thread pool implementation.

**ThreadPoolTaskExecutor**

This implementation can only be used in a Java 5 environment but is also the most commonly used one in that environment. It exposes bean properties for configuring a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor and wraps it in a TaskExecutor. If you need something advanced such as a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, it is recommended that you use a ConcurrentTaskExecutor instead.

Comment: The [latest Spring (4.1.x) documentation for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) has no reference to Java 5.